# Analyzing Protobuf vs JSON and ran into issues with data size

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I was tasked to look at data sizes and process speed (speed to create the data) of equal data in JSON format vs. Protobuf, in Java.

For JSON, I'm using Jackson, and I created a `Subscriptions` class with a `List<HashMap<String,String>` field, called subscriptionList. Each `HashMap` would correspond to 1 subscription. I am reading from a file, each line is "|" delimited for fields, there are 523 fields. I loop through each field assigning to the subscription `HashMap` column name for the key and column value for the value. I loop through each line to create all 1000 subscriptions, I put them into an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`, then I create a `Subscriptions`, and set subscriptionList to the `ArrayList` with 1000 subscriptions. Finally I convert the `Subscriptions` object to string in JSON format, and write that to a text file, measure the size of the text file, and that's how I am measuring the size of the data.

For protobuf, the .proto file look something like,

```
message Subscriptions {
    repeated Subscription subscription = 1;
}
message Subscription {
    map<string, string> attr = 1;
}
```

I loop through each line and each column again, creating 1000 Subscription messages, I then repeatedly added the Subscription messages to a Subscriptions message. I then use the .getSerializedSize method, and that's how I measured the protobuf messages data sizes.

Currently, I see that the two formats give me basically the same data sizes, which I don't understand why. Protobuf messages are already inherently compressed some, and they're known to be less space demanding than raw JSON. I don't know what I am doing wrong, and I ran out of ideas to try.

Comment: This particular example might be the *best* case for JSON.  The difference tends to be most prominent when you have many, many different fields, all with their own nesting.

Comment: To extend on what @Louis says: `map<string,string>` is arguably the *worst* layout for protobuf - it has basically no room to optimize that: it is mostly just UTF8

Answer (score 0):

You won't get much a difference between a map turned to a JSON object and the same map turned to a protobuf message. For example in protobuf there are no quotes around object keys and no braces around the first level message, but this doesn't make much of a difference, specially in large datasets.

You will see some difference in protobuf while using packed repeated fields (only primitive types) since those are converted to binary values hence largely decreasing in size compared to UTF8 encoding in JSON.